# How to define variable's names in feature selection

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I try to define variable's names in feature selection. I have a dataset like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({'a' : [1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0,1, 0 ],
             'b' : ['foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar' ] ,
             'c' : ['foo', 'bar','bar','foo','foo', 'bar','bar','foo','foo', 'bar' ],
                'd' :['d','d','b','a','d','d','a','b','d','a']    })
```

So

```
X, y = df.ix[:, 1:], df.ix[:,[0]]
X_dummy = pd.get_dummies(X)
```

And

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=4).fit_transform(X_dummy, y)
X_new

array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

I get array but i want to know what variable (`b`, `c` or `d` or their dummy options) have to incude in model. How to find out this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scores_` attribute of the fitted selector

```
>> kbest = SelectKBest(chi2, k=4)
>> X_new = kbest.fit_transform(X_dummy, y)
>> X_dummy.columns[kbest.scores_.argsort()[::-1][:4]]
Index(['b_foo', 'b_bar', 'd_a', 'd_d'], dtype='object')
```